# Do I comment or do I edit?

Tags: discussion, comments, editing, answers

There is a really great answer to a question out there that I voted up. But I'm finding myself quibbling with the wording of one particular statement.

I'm not certain, should I just go in and edit? Or should I comment and allow the original answer author to edit? What is the best accepted practice?

The answer is here: 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4089/498

The statement I would like to see amended is this:

> "If you are considering multiple editions of Salesforce in a single
>   organisation, you can create a single salesforce app visible across
>   all editions, but this will need to be deployed to each edition..."

I would put it like this:

> "If you are considering multiple editions of Salesforce in a single
>   organisation, you can deploy a salesforce app to each edition..."

My first instinct was to edit. But my gut is telling me that I should comment. But then I'm thinking maybe this is too much commentary.

Comment: Edit it, I say while using a comment to respond :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do both - as you feel. In this scenario, I would have edited as well.

Comment: I guess it is helpful remembering that edits are always peer reviewed anyway.

Comment: @Peter - After you have 1000 rep you don't need peer review: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit

Comment: Working my way slowly there. :-)

Comment: @Saariko, fixed a small typo there for you :)

Comment: @PeterKnolle This will change when the site leaves beta, I think the rep requirement will become 3000